# How to remove Ubuntu and Install Windows 10 without losing my data?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, windows

I am already installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I want to remove it and change it to windows, but i have an important data where its so big size.

how to install windows 10 without losing my ubuntu data ?

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Because Windows uses the NTFS file system and Linux uses the ext4 file system you'll have to copy/backup the data somewhere before re-installing.

Your options are:

- Upload to the cloud such as Google Drive; or
- Copy data to a USB disk or another external drive; or
- Use the Live USB installer to resize your disk and create an extra NTFS or FAT32 partition and move your data to that partition and be careful not to allow Windows to format it when installing

Comment: Yes, I am backing up data is the one and only way, but I am looking for a way other than backing up data because I don't have a flashdisk.

Comment: Your only option is to use the cloud

Comment: I feel the third option is best. Create a partition and move your data there. So later you can directly use it from Windows.

Comment: so i cant copy data from ext4 file system to NTFS file system ?

Comment: yeah u are right @Jrct :)

Comment: you can copy data from ext4 system to NTFS whilst you are in a Linux OS. But not from windows